# Algorithm to make a face on a photo look fatter?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, image-manipulation

What is the most general and simple approach to make look fatter a face on an image ?I am working with java but programming details are not important i am looking for the algorithm .

Comment: Why not simply stretch it horizontally ?

Comment: I am trying to get more professional result.Something like  iphone application called "fat booth".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to get some Java image morph code, use a fat face picture as a target and morph only the vertexes, not the color. This is a very complex solution for two reasons: First it's hard to code (however you might find some good library) and second, you'll also have to do some face recognition to get the source morph points. But it will probably give the best (most realistic) results.